# Where is the Sparx EA CSV Exchange Specification Stored?

Tags: export-to-csv, enterprise-architect

The CSV Exchange Specification (Publish > CSV > CSV Exchange Specification) definitions seem to be specific to a particular project file or repository. When starting a new project it's a pain having to recreate and there's no mechanism I can find to export or to share.

[image]

Presumably these definitions must be held in an internal database table. Does anyone know which table holds them? This would then provide an import / export mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are stored in the table `t_template`

```
select * from t_template where TemplateType = 'CSV'
```

The column `Template` contains the actual specification of the CSV export/import using name-value pairs

```
delim=*;direction=-1;field0=TagValue_Capa Level;field1=Name;field2=Notes;field3=CSV_KEY;field4=CSV_PARENT_KEY;
```